# What does the '2' in "Ran 2 tests in 0.016s" mean?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am running the tensorflow unit test, but I do not know the meaning of '2' in the output of test. The output is "Ran 2 tests in 0.016s".

```
import tensorflow as tf

class SquareTest(tf.test.TestCase):

  def testSquare(self):
    with self.test_session():
      x = tf.square([2, 3])
      self.assertAllEqual(x.eval(), [4, 9])

if __name__ == '__main__':
  tf.test.main()
```

Comment: Is your question addressed? If so, you can help future users by marking the checkbox beside the correct answer. If not, what can be clarified?

Answer (score 1):

[aryamccarthy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43302787/3574081) is on the right track, but the question remains "Why does the class `SquareTest` count as a test?"

The real answer is a little bit silly. The class `tf.test.TestCase` includes a method called [`test_session()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/901ab86f35bc24461bad6d3145e62874d105038f/tensorflow/python/framework/test_util.py#L299), which is used to create a `tf.Session` with parameters that make it a little easier to configure a specific device for testing. Python's [`unittest.TestCase`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#basic-example) defines all methods whose names start with the letters `test` to be test cases. Therefore all descendants of `tf.test.TestCase` include a "phantom" test called `test_session()`.

Answer (score 0):

The class `SquareTest` and the function `testSquare` count as separate tests. See for yourself:

```
import tensorflow as tf

class SquareTest(tf.test.TestCase):
    pass
if __name__ == '__main__':
  tf.test.main()
# Ran 1 test in 0.000s
```